# How is php supposed to react once actionscript POSTs data to it?

Tags: php, xml, actionscript-3

I have decent PHP and AS3 knowledge, but none regarding connecting the two.
I am trying to use AS3 to send data to PHP, and have PHP save them to a XML.

What I don't get is how php is supposed to react to external code. The AS3 script does not start the page, correct? It just sends data to it? Just executing the actionscript side doesn't work nor does loading the php in the browser manually (with apache running correctly, gibberish echo's funcioning) or reloading it after the AS3 sending. The xml stays empty, no return value to trace. All tutorials deal with before and after, assuming that I know how it is that php will react at all to receiving data from AS3. Can someone tell me my missing link?

If it matters, my relevant AS3:

```
        public function xt(e:MouseEvent):void
    {
        marque = tmarque.text;
        prix = tprix.text;
        couleur = tcouleur.text;
        xmlString = "<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>";
        fichier = new XML(xmlString);
        fichier = <ordinateurs />;
        fichier.marque = marque;
        fichier.couleur = couleur;
        fichier.PRIX = prix;
        var req = new URLRequest("C:/xampplite/htdocs/save_xml.php");
        //(have also tried placing the php in same folder)

        req.data = fichier;
        req.contentType = "text/xml";
        req.method = URLRequestMethod.POST;
        var xmlSendLoad:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
        xmlSendLoad.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onComplete, false, 0, true);
        xmlSendLoad.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, onIOError, false, 0, true);
        xmlSendLoad.load(req);
}

function onComplete(event:Event):void {
try {
    var xmlResponse = new XML(event.target.data);
    TXTtesticle.text = xmlResponse;
    removeEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onComplete);
    removeEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, onIOError);
} catch (err:TypeError) {
    TXTtesticle.text = "An error occured when communicating with server:\n" + err.message;
}
trace (xmlResponse);
placeText();
}
```

and PHP

```
<?php 
if (isset($GLOBALS["HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA"]))
{  
    $xml = $GLOBALS["HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA"]; 
    $file = fopen("data.xml","wb"); 
    fwrite($file, $xml); 
    fclose($file); 
    echo($GLOBALS["HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA"]); 
} 
?>
```

Comment: It's not useful to use `echo` here. Instead log to file (you can re-use the PHP error log for that with the [`trigger_error()`](http://php.net/trigger_error) function, just enable PHP error logging). This is very important, because echoing will go into nirvana as you don't output the response within the AS code. And instead of fopen + fwrite + fclose I suggest to use [`file_put_contents()' ](http://php.net/file_put_contents). And if you use another variable for the condition next to `$xml` you could easily change the code in case `$GLOBALS["HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA"]` not only looks fishy.

Answer (score 1):

Using AS to call PHP is basically exactly the same thing as Ajax. Just rather than an Ajax call from client JS in a browser, its from AS in Flash.

Two issues I see instantly with your code:

(1) `$GLOBALS["HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA"]?` Why? That's deprecated as of PHP 5.6.0. And it was bad practice long before that. There's this thing called `$_POST` that everyone else has been using for a long time now.

(2) `var req = new URLRequest("C:/xampplite/htdocs/save_xml.php");` You don't do URL requests to the local file system. You do URL requests to a web url, like `var req = new URLRequest("http://localhost/save_xml.php");`

To understand what your PHP should do with the POST, you can look at any Ajax tutorial. It need not be AS specific because a client making a http request to a webserver is a client making a http request to a webserver no matter what the client is.

Comment: AS3 can't find the new path for the file, although my browser itself can load it just fine from localhost. Any ideas?

Comment: What do you mean by "AS3 can't find the new path for the file" ?

Comment: Whereas it would before do nothing with the file, now using the http://localhost/save_xml.php path it freezes and the console outputs Cannot display source code at this location.